# Is it possible to have a collection of Object<T> classes?

Tags: c#

I have an object that I want to put into a List or Collection. Is there a way to do that without having the T specified?

I want to do something like this: `List<CommonProperty<T>>`

Here's the object for reference:

```
internal class CommonProperty<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PropType Type { get; set; }
    public List<T> PossibleValues { get; set; }
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (!_value.Equals(value))
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OrderedDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use open generic types like that.

You could have a `List<CommonProperty<T>>` within a context where `T` is already a type parameter:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    static void Bar()
    {
        // This is fine, but is not what you're looking for - it uses
        // the type parameter T as the type argument
        List<CommonProperty<T>> list = new List<CommonProperty<T>>();
    }
}
```

Typically the solution here is to have a *non-generic* base class or interface which the generic class or interface derives from:

```
// Consider making it abstract
internal class CommonProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PropType Type { get; set; }
}

internal class CommonProperty<T> : CommonProperty
{
    public List<T> PossibleValues { get; set; }
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            // TODO: Is this really necessary?
            if (!_value.Equals(value))
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then create a `List<CommonProperty>`... although be aware that it's entirely possible that you could end up with an element which wasn't a `CommonProperty<T>` at all that way.

From the `List<CommonProperty>` you'd be able to retrieve the names and types of all the properties - but the values wouldn't be available without casting to the specific type. You *could* have an `abstract object Value { get; set; }` property in the base class, which was then overridden in the derived class, potentially - but it's not clear whether that's necessary or helpful in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is to define an interface to match an un-typed (specific) `CommonProperty`, using `Object` instead of the `T`. Then have your `CommonProperty<T>` implement that interface. Now you can use the interface with your list.

But this isn't great. You'll lose a lot of nice type checking, and have to do more casting. If this is the primary way you'll use these objects, there's not much point to having a generic class at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to put a mixture of generics instantiated with different type arguments into the same collection. Such collection would not be useful anyway, because the caller would be expected to supply `T` for each item at compile time.

Suppose you could do what you want, i.e.

```
// imagine that you could do this
List<CommonProperty<T>> mixedList = GetAllProperties();
```

You would be forced to supply `T` once you start using items from that list, i.e.

```
foreach (CommonProperty<T> prop in mixedList) {
    ... //             ^^^
    ... // Here you would need to specify T, but you don't know which one
}
```

In other words, such list would be unusable.

A list of properties of a specific type, on the other hand, would be useful:

```
List<CommonProperty<string>> stringPropList = GetPropertiesOfType<string>();
foreach (CommonProperty<string> prop in stringPropList ) {
    ...
}
```

Therefore, one solution to your problem would be building `GetPropertiesOfType<T>` method returning `List<CommonProperty<T>>` bound to type `T` from the caller.

An alternative approach would be to make `CommonProperty` non-generic, and let the caller check the type at runtime:

```
internal class CommonProperty {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PropType Type { get; set; }
    public List<T> GetPossibleValues<T> { get; set; }
    private object _value;
    public T GetValue<T>() {
        return (T)_value;
    }
    public void SetValue<T>(T val) {
        _value = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Servy, I see you are still enjoying the silly game that you play. Well, good luck with that, dude.